# Border is removed when animation is played

Tags: jquery, css, animation

My code below works fine except that at the beginning of the animation the border of `#progressBarThumb` disappears and reappears at the end of the animation!

```
#progressBarContainer {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    height: 20px;
    width: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9px;
    right: 10px;
}
#progressBar {
    height:20px;
    background-color: #f12506;
    width:0%;
}
#progressBarThumb {
    float: right;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #f12506;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#f12506;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBarContainer">
    <div id="progressBar">
        <div id="progressBarThumb"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
this.setProgressBar = function(value, maxValue) {
    var porcentage = (value /maxValue)*100 + '%';
    $('#progressBar').animate({'width':porcentage});
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x7n6d2ny/

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because by default the `animate()` method sets `overflow: hidden` on the affected element. You need to override that in CSS:

```
#progressBar {
    overflow: visible !important;
    /* other styles here... */
}
```

[**Updated example**](https://jsfiddle.net/x7n6d2ny/1/)

Also note that your fiddle was not functional as you didn't include jQuery.